# Why <svg> is not showing output in browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

Actually I want to make a TagClouder. Thats why I have to use 'svg' tag. When I run below code then it shows nothing on the browser but if I open the 'Inspect element' then it shows that the value of '#set_texts' is 'Tag Cloud'. If I use div without using 'g' tag then its shows output in the browser but if I use 'g' tag then it shows nothing on the browser. How can I get it?

HTML :

```
<svg width="960" height="600">
    <g transform="translate(480,300)" id="set_texts">
    </g>
</svg>
```

JQuery :

```
$('#set_texts').text("Tag Cloud");
```

Comment: what about .html("your value")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a `<text>` tag , it should work:

```
<svg width="960" height="600">
    <text transform="translate(480,300)" id="set_texts">
    </text>
</svg>
```